# Solution for [Country_of_origin =NULL] error in amazon MWS API required after July 2021

Tags: amazon-mws

I faced an issue in the Product API of AMAZON MWS where its displaying error country_of_origin=NULL and required error return by API.

A value is missing from one or more required columns from this group: [country_of_origin = null].
I found the solution for that, Hope it can help anyone searching for the same.

```
 <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
  <SKU>5678999993</SKU>
  <StandardProductID>
    <Type>ASIN</Type>
    <Value>5678999993</Value>
  </StandardProductID>
  <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
  <DescriptionData>
    <Title>MULE 3L - Racing Red/Pitch Blue</Title>
    <Brand>CAMELBAK</Brand>
    <Description>This is a test product description.</Description>
    <BulletPoint>Perfect for hiking.</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>Bladder for hydration.</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="AUD">100.00</MSRP>
    <Manufacturer>CAMELBAK</Manufacturer>
    <ItemType>outdoor-backpacks</ItemType>
   <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
  </DescriptionData>
  <ProductData>
    <Outdoors>
      <ProductType>
        <OutdoorRecreationProduct>
        </OutdoorRecreationProduct>
      </ProductType>
      <VariationData>
      </VariationData>      
    </Outdoors>
  </ProductData>
</Product>
</Message>
```

Need to pass US , Country name should be in country code. and this attribute must need to add in the DescriptionData block of XML like above.